# How to implement a UINavigationController to a standard UIView

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, nested

This is the structure of my application currently:

- UIWindow

  - UIViewController (Root View Controller)

    - UINavigationController
    - UITableView
  - UIViewController (PresentModalViewControllerAnimated:YES)

    - UITableView

This is how I want it to be:

- UIWindow

  - UIViewController (Root View Controller)

    - UINavigationController
    - UITableView
  - UIViewController (PresentModalViewControllerAnimated:YES)

    - UINavigationController
    - UITableView

I have a view that slides up and I want that view to have its own UINavigationController. It's for the app settings so I want to have nested options.

Any ideas how to do this?

The application type was a Navigation app to start with which is where the Root View Controller's UINavigationController came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `UINavigationController` inherits from `UIViewController` so you can present it as a modal view controller. I've created a simple test application and this approach worked fine.

To present navigation controller:

```
ChildController* controller = [[ChildController alloc] initWithNibName:@"childController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController* childNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
[self presentModalViewController:childNav animated:YES];    
[controller release];
[childNav release];
```

Then to dismiss modal controller from whatever controller in its hierarchy use

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```